# Use Apache 2.0 license or AGPLv3 licensed Software

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, agpl-3.0, hardware, logos

1. I want to sell a custom piece of Hardware with my own company's name with an Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 LTS on it. Is that allowed?
2. I want to run on this server an Apache 2.0 licensed or AGPLv3 licensed software and I want to customize the GUI of that software and change the logo of the software. Is that allowed?
3. I want to give two years warranty on that hardware. Is that allowed?

Comment: Everything you've asked is allowed **provided you honour the obligations that the licences of the software involved place upon you**.  In the case of the AGPL application, you may also wish to warn prospective purchasers of their obligations under the AGPL; that last is not strictly an obligation upon you, but your customer service number is going to ring off the hook if you don't do that.  The problem is your question gives no indication whether you know about these obligations., which makes it hard to answer.

Comment: i have no clue at all

Comment: Then you should start by reading the licences and seeing what they allow, and what they require in exchange.  They're not complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to sell a custom piece of Hardware with my own company's name with an Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 LTS on it. Is that allowed?

In general yes, but Ubuntu® has [specific branding guidelines](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy) and in some case you may need some additional OEM licensing agreement from them.

> I want to run on this server an Apache 2.0 licensed or AGPLv3 licensed software and I want to customize the GUI of that software and change the logo of the software. Is that allowed?

As MadHatter mentioned in a comment, yes this is allowed " provided you honour the obligations that the licences of the software involved place upon you." This is even IMHO one of the tenets of FLOSS: having access to the source code and being able to modify software.

You will have of meet the license requirements and AGPL and Apache are quite different. In the case of AGPL-licensed, this may be considered a modification and this has specific implications in terms of your obligations and which conditions of the license are triggered.

> I want to give two years warranty on that hardware. Is that allowed?

The warranty you provide on hardware is your problem and your choice and has nothing to do with the software. You may also provide warranty on the software, but there since mots FLOSS-licensed code disclaims all warranties, you would have to bear the warranty burden alone.

> i have no clue at all

That's OK... there are excellent resources on this QA site to help you! I would also strongly suggest that once you are familiar with the gist of open source licensing you contact a lawyer to help you make the right choices.